# Oracle - "Sql developer" database copy utility - Src/tgt different schema

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to copy table from One database to another. Source and target schema are different. I m trying "Sql developer" for this using database copy utility. However, I m not able to find option to select schema name for the target.

I m attaching screenshot here for the reference. 
[image]

Error Message :-

```
Moving Data for object XXXXXX
Error occurred inserting data for TABLE: XXXXXX.  Batch 1 containing 500 rows failed. 
  ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]SQL Developer provides the Database Copy wizard for quickly copying data from one schema to another.

In your example HEDGEP connection  is pointing to the source schema and DIWD1 is pointing to the destination schema. If you intend to copy multiple schemas using SQL Developer then you will need to define multiple source and destination connections each pointing to the respective source and target schemas and then run the wizard separately for each of those pairs.

Comment: HEDGEP and DIWD1 are different databases. My problem is I want to copy table from HEDGEP - X schema to DIWD1 y schema. Hope question is clear now. :) thanks

Comment: When you are connecting to connection HEDGEP in SQL Developer to which schema does it point to? This would be your source schema. Similarly the DIWD1 connection will be pointing to the target schema, though on a different database. Can you right click on these connections and Go to Properties. The username displayed there is the schema name.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. Schema name mentioned there is the correct one. I mean username mentioned there is schema where I want to copy the table -destination

Comment: For source - its different schema. I m selecting required schema while selecting the table name (specify object screen).

Comment: I think I got the problem.. I m not able to see DDL defination in sql developer for the destination table.. its giving message as - "Unable to render TABLE DDL for object Schema_Name.Table_Name with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator."

Comment: you need SELECT CATALOG role to reliably generate DDL for objects not in your own schema